# Best database for multi million row store/query

Tags: database, nosql

We have a database that has been growing for around 5 years. The main table has near 100 columns and 700 million rows (and growing).

The common use case is to count how many rows match a given criteria, that is:
select count(*) where column1='TypeA' and column2='BlockC'.

The other use case is to retrieve the rows that match a criteria.

The queries started by taking a bit of time, now they take a couple of minutes. 
I want to find some DBMS that allows me to make the two use cases as fast as possible.

I've been looking into some Column store databases and Apache Cassandra but still have no idea what is the best option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Update: these days I'd recommend Hive 3 or PrestoDB for big data analysis

I am going to assume this is an analytic (historical) database with no current data. If not, you should consider separating your dbs.

You are going to want a few features to help speed up analysis:

- Materialized views. This is essentially pre-calculating values, and then storing the results for later analysis. MySQL and Postgres (coming soon in Postgres 9.3) do not support this, but you can mimic with triggers.
- easy OLAP analysis. You could use Mondrian OLAP server (java), but then Excel doesn't talk to it easily, but JasperSoft and Pentaho do.
- you might want to change the schema for easier OLAP analysis, ie the star schema. Good book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247)

If you want open source, I'd go Postgres (doesn't choke on big queries like mysql can), plus Mondrian, plus Pentaho.

If not open source, then best bang for buck is likely Microsoft SQL Server with Analysis Services.

Comment: Thanks. I have a problem in the description. He have 7 billion row. Just did some estimates it will grow around 1 billion per year. With the new definition do you still advise the same solution?